# Como obtener el id de un select en angular 4

Tags: angular

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="power" ng-model="idcaptured2" required>
    <option *ngFor="let pow of mod" [value]="pow.id">{{pow.denominacion}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

el component :

```
captureId()    
{
    console.log('valor del select'+this.idcaptured+' '+this.idcaptured2);
}
```

Comment: Es raro que necesites el ID de algo si estás usando Angular, quizas puedas hacer algo de otra forma. Por que necesitas el id?

Comment: para guardar en base de datos el id de cada select

Comment: Deberías de tener claro que hay una gran diferencia entre AngularJS y Angular(2+), son dos productos diferentes. El uno trabaja con Javascript puro, mientras el otro es un concepto diferente al trabajar con Typescript (el cual ha de el cual ha de ser transcrito a un lenguaje que los navegadores puedan entender, osea en Javascript ). Además de que la sintaxis de un modelo sería algo como `[(ngModel)]="name"` y no como lo tienes tu `ng-model="name"`... Esto para las personas que pasen por aqui en algún momento (con términos sin aclarar respecto a versiones)

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente caso la variable index, está capturando el id del select.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="power" ng-model="idcaptured2" required>
    <option *ngFor="let pow of mod, let i = index" [value]="pow.id">{{pow.denominacion}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```